# How to port my Flash (Flixel with Flex actually) made game to Steam?

Tags: flash, steam, haxeflixel, flixel

I've done my Googling and apparently there is only two ways, one is to use HaxeFlixel and another is Adobe AIR. I'm a bit on a tight schedule and can't test them both. What do you guys would recommend and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has done both (released a steam game using original flash flixel, and now working on a haxeflixel game), if your primary concern is that you are on a tight schedule, you should ABSOLUTELY go with Adobe AIR.

It doesn't take much to add Adobe AIR support. Just be sure that you use the captive runtime feature when packaging:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html

Do note that Adobe AIR support on linux is a huge pain. You can manage to make it palatable for your users with some crazy scripts and targeting the last supported version of Adobe AIR on linux, but even then you'll only get compatibility with mainline linux distros, not SteamOS, and so you'll be denied the "support linux" icon on Steam.

So if you really need SteamOS/Linux support, I would vote that you should port your game to HaxeFlixel.

If you just need to get something done now, go with Adobe AIR and ship your game, and worry about porting it to HaxeFlixel later.

HaxeFlixel has a lot of advantages and new features and can reach many more platforms than flash+flixel, but there will be additional work as all these new features have changed the HaxeFlixel API somewhat from the original flash Flixel API. That said it's much less work than porting to anything else (like Unity or Monogame or raw C++)

My credentials: I'm the developer of Defender's Quest, a successful steam game that uses Flash+Flixel+AIR, and I happen to be a core contributor to HaxeFlixel.

Comment: Thanks. Some questions though:

1) My schedule is about 1 month. So do you think it's enough to go with HaxeFlixel? I think it's a better one since will probably let me add Steam Achievements and other things more easily rather than the flash flixel but I'm not sure how long will it take to port it to HaxeFlixel.

2) Do you have any advice on releasing my game on Steam? it's this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5oPGbcAfeQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: 3) I've followed your advice and tried to add AIR packaging to my game but I've faced a lot of issues. Is there any written guide for adding AIR support to Flixel games?